# Document Set , setting fields in PS or C#

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am working with document sets in SharePoint Online. Is there a way with Powershell or C# I can set the values of the document set fields?

Any examples?

It's not clear from what I have seen on the internet.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by document set fields? do you mean, metadata of Document Set?

Comment: Yep, document set metadata

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the document set object `$docSet`, the metadata of the document set can be updated as below.

```
$docSet.Folder.Properties["MetadataProp1"]="test"
$docSet.Folder.Update()
$docLib.Update()
$web.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following C# code for your reference.

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/lz";

var login = "lz@xx.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "**";
string documentLibraryName = "DocumentLibrary";
string documentSetName = "DdocumentSet1";
string propertyName = "field1";
string updatePropertyValue = "LZ";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
SharePointOnlineCredentials onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
ctx.Credentials = onlineCredentials;

Web site = ctx.Web;

List docLib = site.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibraryName);
ctx.Load(docLib);
CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
caml.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='text'>"+documentSetName+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"; ;
ListItemCollection items = docLib.GetItems(caml);             
ctx.Load(items);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if (items.Count != 0)
{
    ListItem item = items[0];
    var properties = item.Folder.Properties;
    properties[propertyName] = updatePropertyValue;
    item.Folder.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```